# Merge [android-navigation-component] into [android-architecture-navigation]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Both these tags [android-navigation-component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-navigation-component) and [android-architecture-navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-architecture-navigation) refer to the Android Jetpack Navigation library provided by Google at https://developer.android.com/jetpack. Unifying them makes sense.

[android-architecture-navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-architecture-navigation) has more questions and is consistent with [android-architecture-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-architecture-components) or [android-architecture-lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-architecture-lifecycle) or [android-architecture-paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-architecture-paging)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [android-architecture-navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-architecture-navigation) was undoubtedly being used for the same purpose as [android-navigation-component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-navigation-component) was being used, and many questions had both the tags. The tag wikis were also speaking of the same thing (the [android-navigation-component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-navigation-component) tag wiki was plagiarized and therefore didn't save it)

I merged the tags in the direction that you had earlier proposed, and also added the other tag as a synonym.